# Get input name on cliking a link

Tags: jquery, input, get

```
<div id="myId">
<inut type="text" name="what I should get">
<a href="#" name="one" class="add"><img src="add.png" /></a>
</div>
```

I need a jquery function to get the input name when clicked on the link I tried with

```
$(':input').attr('name');
```

But it doesn't work, could you help me please? Thanks
it's not a problem to transform the link in a button.

Comment: `<input type="text"`, not `<inut`

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have already defined a click-event on your a-element and are now in the function that is called by the click:

```
$(Event.currentTarget).closest('#id').find('input').attr('name')
```

Or, if you are sure, that the a-element is always a sibling to the input:

```
$(Event.currentTarget).siblings('input').attr('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$("input").attr("name");
```

Comment: What difference is it going to make ? `$(':input')` is a perfectly valid selector. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your markup:

Change this

```
<inut type="text"
```

to this one:

```
<input type="text"
```

and try this jQuery as per your markup:

```
$('#myId').on('click', '.add', function(){
    console.log($(this).siblings(':text').attr('name'));
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NbbT8/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? If you have got "a href" and "input" in common div.

```
$(a).click( function()
{
     alert( $(this).parent().children('input').attr('name') );
});
```

Writed from head without computer... sorry.